# CanCan on permissions for record user belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, belongs-to, user-permissions

I have the following association:

```
class Branch<ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end
```

and

```
class Employees<ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

now I want certain employees with a :general_manager role to be able to update the branch information for the branch they belong to. (Employees are users and are able to log into the system)

That is: a user is able to update a record he or she belongs to.

I'm thinking this will work, but I'm not sure:

```
if current_employee.role? :general_manager
  can :update, Branch, :id => user.branch_id
end
```

Is that alright?